# Conceptual question on Recognition vs conformation

Tags: classification, experiment-design, multi-class

So, this is a conceptual question on the design of a model. I am getting started with ML and on a slight time crunch to get some results. My problem is not a classical recognition problem. It’s more of a confirmation problem. For example, in the digit recognition problem, my task is not exactly to recognize which digit is written but rather to confirm if the written digit is digit x. I already know beforehand that the digit is supposed to be digit x. So let's say I have 15 digits I can think of two approaches:

1. I train a multi-class classifier to identify written digits. The output of the classifier is a confidence matrix that gives the recognition confidence of being recognized as each of the 15 digits. And if the confidence of the digit x is higher than the rest or a certain threshold, I take it as a confirmation that it was indeed written x.
2. I train 15 binary classifiers, and since I already know what the digit is supposed to be, I just pass it to the corresponding classifier and check for the result.

I know both approaches can get my task done. But I want to know which approach is better according to the problem scenario or if both are the same thing conceptually.